# Como arreglar el codigo para que no permita numeros <0?

Tags: python, bucles

La idea del codigo es sumar la cantidad de minutos de pelicula y comprobar si es posible verlas todas seguidas... quisiera saber como hacer para que, si el usuario ingresa una pelicula cuya duracion sea <0 (irracional), el programa se cierre automaticamente. Desde ya, gracias!

```
capacidad = int(input("capacidad"))
peliculas = int(input("peliculas"))
minutos = int(input("minutos (presione 0 para salir)"))
total = 0
while minutos >0:
    while (minutos !=0):
        total =+ minutos 
        minutos = int(input("minutos (presione 0 para salir)"))
    if (capacidad < total):
        print ("NO")
    else:
        print ("SI")
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no pones un if antes de while para validar si los minutos son menor a cero y para salir entonces importa sys.

```
import sys
capacidad = int(input("capacidad"))
peliculas = int(input("peliculas"))
minutos = int(input("minutos (presione 0 para salir)"))
total = 0
if minutos < 0 : sys.exit(0)
while minutos >0:
    while (minutos !=0):
        total =+ minutos 
        minutos = int(input("minutos (presione 0 para salir)"))
    if (capacidad < total):
        print ("NO")
    else:
        print ("SI")
```

Comment: no es necesario importar sys, pues la función `exit()` ya viene por defecto en python y sirve para terminar la ejecución del programa